# R: Draw lines which "fit" the same shape as a reference line

Tags: r, graph

I'm currently working on a project were I need to indentify lines which have the same kind of shape, e.g:

```
yrefer = c(0.2900,0.3189,0.4097,0.3609,0.3762,0.5849,0.7144)
```

For example take a look at the following plot, I want R to recognize these two red lines for example as a fitting shape, also if there is a little deviation(say 0.05 from the reference line(in blue)).
[image]
So I want to write a code which checks based on a list of y coördinates if these y coördinates fit the yrefer line, were a deviation of 0.05 is permitted.
I'm not sure if this is possible in R, but if it is I know there are people here that can help me out.
**notice**: What I mean with the deviation of 0.05:
let's say we have a line which is:

```
1.2900 1.3189 1.4097 1.3609 1.3762 1.5849 1.7144
```

this would be exactly the same line but then 1 higher then the yrefer line, but with the deviation of 0.05 I mean that if some y coördinates differ 0.05 from what you would expect them to be, so in this example I should expect them to be 1 higher for ever yRefer coördinate, but if one of them is 0.98 higher I would still accept this as a "fitting" line, because it's devation is < `0.05`.
To clarify I drawed some possiblities(there are a lot more of course!) which should be accepted as correct for the first y-value:
[image]
I hope it's clear, if not let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Johannes' answer generalizes, e.g:

```
y_ref = c(0, 0, 0)
y_test = c(.03,.03, -.06) #then test_line fails even though, let:
y_test = y_test +.011
abs(y_test - y_ref) #never outside the .05 range
test_line(y_test) #failed
```

I think you want something like:

```
n = length(y_test)
d1 = y_test[-1] - y_test[-n]
d2 = y_ref[-1] - y_ref[-n]
max(cumsum(d2 - d1)) - min(cumsum(d2 - d1)) #shouldn't be >= .1
```

Comment: Thankyou, can you please explain what this code does?

Comment: I tried to use your example but this will give met 0 for every test (I pasted the code you suggested combined with the code I have in my question, maybe I did something wrong)

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to type in n = length(y_test)

Comment: The idea is to look at the *difference* in the cumulative amount gained/lost in the two lines. If the test line exceeds the reference line by .05 at a point, but it never dropped more than .01 below the reference line, than we can just shift the reference line up by .02 so that the maximum distance between the test and reference line in either direction is .03

Comment: The last line of code tells you whether there is a possible shift in the test/ref line so that distance between the two lines at any point would never be >=.05. The value shouldn't change due to any shift in the test or ref line. Let me know if it works for what your're doing/if I misinterpreted the question.

Answer (score 1):

Just account for the different y mean.

```
newline<- c(1.25, 1.3189, 1.4097, 1.4609, 1.3762, 1.5249, 1.7144)
newline2<-newline+mean(yrefer)-mean(newline)
sd(newline2-yrefer)  #Can use var or whatever you want here.
```

This can all be packed into a function like.

```
lindev<- function(x){
newline2<-x+mean(yrefer)-mean(x)
return(sd(newline2-yrefer))}

lindev(c(1.25, 1.3189, 1.4097, 1.4609, 1.3762, 1.5249, 1.7144))
```

Note this will only work if the x coordinates are the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
y_ref <- c(0.2900,0.3189,0.4097,0.3609,0.3762,0.5849,0.7144)

y_test_1 <- c(1.2900, 1.3187,  1.4097, 1.3609, 1.3762, 1.5849, 1.7144)
y_test_2 <- c(1.2900, 1.2189,  1.4097, 1.3609, 1.3762, 1.5849, 1.7144)

test_line <- function(y_test) {
  overall_deviation <- mean(y_test - y_ref)
  residuals <- y_test - y_ref - overall_deviation
  if (any(abs(residuals) > 0.05)) message("Failed")
  else message("Passed")
}

test_line(y_test_1)
test_line(y_test_2)
```